# AlarmManager intent data is not exist on the BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I am developing an alarm.

I have a data class (Parcelable).

So when I create the alarm, I pass the object into the intent.

But when I got the alarm in BroadcastReceiver, there are no data.

So I tested something.

When I put "String" instead of "Parcelable" class, it works fine!!!

Only when I put "Parcleable" data, it doesn't work!!!

Oh! I tested with Serializable, but it doesn't work too.

My Parcelable class is defined using "Kotlin - @Parcelize".
So I removed the annotation and implemented the Parcelable by my-self.
But the result same. (Not work)

And the Parcelable class is "data class".
So I tried to change it to "class", but the result same...

Does AlarmManager only support a primitive type with String?

Or... is it the android bug?

Answer (score 0):

Wow...

It is intended behavior...

I found a link...

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37112802

I still don't know why it is intended behavior...

Answer (score 0):

The annotation of `@Parcelize` will auto generate parcelize funcation with your `parcelable member` in your class.

The others which are not parcelable member still need to handle by yourself.

And same as `Serialize`.

I'm surely intent with broadcast can pass serialize object (such as `ArrayList<String>`), so I guess there is something member you have not handle yet.